# rust use bufwriter with RC of File

Tags: rust, buffer

I am trying to create a `struct` that can read and write to an opened `File`.

```
struct Store {
    lock: RwLock<()>,
    file: Rc<File>,           // read
    buf: BufWriter<Rc<File>>, // write
    size: u64,
}

impl Store {
    pub fn new(file: File) -> io::Result<Store> {
        let m = file.metadata()?;
        let size = m.len();
        let f = Rc::new(file);
        Ok(Store {
            lock: RwLock::new(()),
            file: f,
            buf: BufWriter::new(f.clone()),
            size,
        })
    }
}
```

I would like to use `BufWriter` for better performance. However, the `Rc<File>` is writable and compilation would fail. If I let `BufWriter` own the `File`, then there is lack of file handle for reading.

How to handle this situation? Should I open the file twice, and one for reading and one for writing?

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code is troublesome as stated is that, [while there's a `Write` implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#implementors) for `&File`, there's no such implementation for `Rc<File>`. We can fix that using a wrapper that contains `Rc<File>` and implements `Write`:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct RcFile(Rc<File>);

impl io::Write for RcFile {
    fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
        let mut file: &File = &*self.0;
        file.write(buf)
    }
    fn flush(&mut self) -> io::Result<()> {
        let mut file: &File = &*self.0;
        file.flush()
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=75fc2d26ce8297b22b25ccf1b627061a)

However, I think that you should consider alternatives to this. The problem with what you're trying to do is that, if you write some data, then seek and read while forgetting to flush the `BufWriter`, the data that's in the `BufWriter`'s buffer will be written in the wrong place on the next write operation.

Instead, I would suggest that *whenever you plan to write* you create a BufWriter on the spot, then use it for the write operations. In particular, you can get an `&File` from the `Store` (there is no need to use `Rc`, now) and wrap that as `BufWriter<&File>`.

```rust
struct Store {
    lock: RwLock<()>,
    file: File,
    size: u64,
}

impl Store {
    // ... fn new() ...

    pub fn writer(&self) -> BufWriter<&File> {
        BufWriter::new(&self.file)
    }
}
```

Or, if you are going to be using the writer in ways that aren't amenable to using a borrow of the `Store`, you can explicitly alternate between "wrapped in a BufWriter" or "wrapped in a BufReader" (or not wrapped):

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io;
use std::mem;

struct Store {
    file: BufRwFile,
}

enum BufRwFile {
    Read(io::BufReader<File>),
    Write(io::BufWriter<File>),
    /// only observed if there was an IO error in a bad time
    Broken,
}

impl Store {
    pub fn new(file: File) -> io::Result<Store> {
        Ok(Store {
            file: BufRwFile::Read(io::BufReader::new(file)),
        })
    }

    pub fn prepare_read(&mut self) -> Result<(), io::Error> {
        self.file = match mem::replace(&mut self.file, BufRwFile::Broken) {
            BufRwFile::Read(buf_reader) => BufRwFile::Read(buf_reader),
            BufRwFile::Write(buf_writer) => match buf_writer.into_inner() {
                Ok(file) => BufRwFile::Read(io::BufReader::new(file)),
                Err(e) => return Err(e.into_error()),
            },
            BufRwFile::Broken => BufRwFile::Broken,
        };
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn prepare_write(&mut self) -> Result<(), io::Error> {
        self.file = match mem::replace(&mut self.file, BufRwFile::Broken) {
            BufRwFile::Write(buf_writer) => BufRwFile::Write(buf_writer),
            BufRwFile::Read(buf_reader) => {
                BufRwFile::Write(io::BufWriter::new(buf_reader.into_inner()))
            }
            BufRwFile::Broken => BufRwFile::Broken,
        };
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d1accbb4fa5eeec2cd8f2305264fa06a)

Comment: Thanks for the tip that &File is writable.
I managed to address the issue with lifetime annotation to let Store reference to the File instead of own it, while Store and File has same lifetime.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3a70afe5497fdf70d27320228cac905a

Comment: You caught the caveat that the `read` needs to sync with `write`. A mutex is used here, and the buffer is always flushed before the `read`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of what exactly you are trying to achieve.

But if you want to open a file, make a bunch of changes, and then write it back, it would be more efficient to hold the contents of the file in memory and have a lock on those contents.

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::fs;
use std::io;
use std::io::Write;
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::sync::RwLock;

struct Store {
    content: RwLock<Rc<RefCell<String>>>,
    path: std::path::PathBuf,
}

impl Store {
    pub fn new(path: &std::path::Path) -> io::Result<Store> {
        let contents = fs::read_to_string(path)?;
        Ok(Store {
            content: RwLock::new(Rc::new(RefCell::new(contents))),
            path: path.to_owned(),
        })
    }

    pub fn read_content(&self) -> String {
        self.content.read().unwrap().borrow().to_string()
    }

    pub fn change_content(&self, new_content: String) {
        self.content.write().unwrap().replace(new_content);
    }

    pub fn write_content_to_file(&self) -> io::Result<()> {
        let mut file = std::fs::File::open(&self.path)?;
        file.write_all(self.content.read().unwrap().borrow().as_bytes())
    }

    pub fn write_with_buf_writer(&self) -> io::Result<()> {
        let file = std::fs::File::open(&self.path)?;
        let mut writer = std::io::BufWriter::new(file);
        writer.write_all(self.content.read().unwrap().borrow().as_bytes())
    }
}
```

To undestand why I added RefCell, you can read [this chapter of the rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/book/ch15-04-rc.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. I can see there are multiple approaches to address the issue. I got inspired by `&File` and comes up with this solution using lifetime.

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io;
use std::io::{BufWriter, Write};
use std::sync::Mutex;

const LEN_WIDTH: u64 = 8;

struct Store<'s> {
    mu: Mutex<()>,
    file: &'s File,           // read
    buf: BufWriter<&'s File>, // write
    size: u64,
}

impl<'s> Store<'s> {
    pub fn new(file: &'s File) -> io::Result<Store<'s>> {
        let m = file.metadata()?;
        Ok(Store {
            mu: Mutex::new(()),
            file,
            buf: BufWriter::new(&file),
            size: m.len(),
        })
    }

    pub fn append(&mut self, p: &[u8]) -> io::Result<(u64, u64)> {
        let _l = self.mu.lock().unwrap();
        let pos = self.size;
        let b = (p.len() as u64).to_be_bytes() as [u8; 8];
        let buf = &mut self.buf;
        buf.write_all(&b)?;
        let mut w = buf.write(p)? as u64;
        w += LEN_WIDTH;
        self.size += w;
        Ok((w, pos))
    }

    pub fn read(&mut self, _pos: u64) -> io::Result<Vec<u8>> {
        let _l = self.mu.lock().unwrap();
        let b = &mut self.buf;
        b.flush()?;

        // TODO: read at the pos

        Ok(vec![])
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use std::fs::OpenOptions;

    #[test]
    fn test_store() {
        let file = OpenOptions::new()
            .read(true)
            .write(true)
            .create(true)
            .open("test_store")
            .unwrap();
        let mut store = Store::new(&file).unwrap();
        let r = store.append(&[1]);
        assert!(r.is_ok());
    }
}
```